# What's the best way to find all possible combinations of a numeric string in Python and compare them with a given string?

Tags: python

i've no idea how to resolve my problem. i ve a string like '0.0.0' and i need to find all possible combinination, like '0.0.1', '0.0.2'....... '9.9.9' then compare with another string if is bigger or no.
no i've code like this

```
K = 1

    res = []
    for ele in version_string:

        if ele.isdigit():
            res.append(str(int(ele) + K))
            version_string = res
            version_string = ''.join(version_string)
        else:
            res.append(ele)

    print(str(version_string))
```

output

```
0.0
1.1
2.2
3.3
4.4
5.5
6.6
```

this code only increment every number by one but i need all combination.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import itertools

for numstr in ('.'.join(map(str, p)) for p in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=3)):
    print(numstr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without the aid of additional modules then:

```
s = '0.0.0'

def combos(s):
    w = s.count('.') + 1
    for x in range(10**w):
        yield '.'.join(f'{x:0{w}}')

def func(s):
    for combo in combos(s):
        print(combo)

func(s)
```